# matching expression to retreive first function name using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a below string

```
TimeStampDiff(SQL_TSI_DAY,  TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY, 2,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" ) ,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" )
```

This does not match my regular expression pattern on testing in https://pythex.org/

```
^\s*([\w]+)\s*\(.*?\)$
```

But I have a exactly similar expression as shown below that matches my regex pattern

```
TimeStampDiff(SQL_TSI_DAY,  TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY, 2,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" ) ,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" )
```

I have tested both expressions with same regex pattern but the first does not match and second one matches.
What could be the reason please help!!

Comment: What are you trying to match here?  Your question forgot to tell us this important piece of information.

Comment: So my regular expression matched the entire string and retreives the first function name in my case **TimeStampDiff** would be the result

Comment: There is a space at the end of the first string, and it is a typo. All you need to do is remove `$` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Python` does not support `recursive regex`, you can enable
it by installing `regex` module with:

```
pip install regex
```

Then you can say something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import regex

s = 'TimeStampDiff(SQL_TSI_DAY,  TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_DAY, 2,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" ) ,  "function_test"."ORDERS"."ORDER_DATE" ) '

#m = regex.match(r'(\w+)\s*\((?:[^()]+|(?R))*\)', s)
m = regex.match(r'(\w+)\s*\(([^()]+|\(\s*(?2)\s*\)|(?R))*\)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))   # prints "TimeStampDiff"
```

where `(?R)` represents the entire regex recursively.
Then the regex above matches the nested function call by balancing
the count of left parentheses and the right parentheses.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/9VrcGU/1)

Comment: If we look at this string it does not match correctly **Concat(upper("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ),Concat(("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_ID" ),Replace(("Function_Testing"."CUSTOMERS"."WEBSITE" ), (\'a\'),(\'s\'))))**

Comment: Okay, good point. I should have considered the case the arguments include parens even though your original string did not. I've updated my answer.

Comment: regex doesnot works for this expression`Concat((Upper("Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" )) ,(  Concat("Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ,  Replace(("Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME") ,( 'a'),( 's')) ) ))`..please check them what is the reason

Comment: and it doesnt work if i use multiple brackets for parameters `Concat(upper("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ),Concat(("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_ID" ),Replace(("Function_Testing"."CUSTOMERS"."WEBSITE" ), (((\'a\'))),(\'s\'))))`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've updated my answer. Now it will match regardless of the extra parentheses around the function arguments. `(?2)` also denotes the recursive regex which represents the 2nd capture group.

Comment: why that group 2 is added its creating lot of confusion

Comment: Let us simplify the whole string as `func(args)`. Then `(?R)` refers to the whole function string including the function name while `(?2)` represents the `args` potion in this case. We cannot match multiple parens in the `args` without using `(?2)`. Note that capure group 1 is already used to assign the function name.

Comment: what will be the result of group2

Comment: In other words `func(func(args))` is a recusion with `(?R)`. `func((args))` is a recursion with `(?2)`. Both recursions are required to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The first string has a space character at the end. Since the regex pattern searches for a closing parathesis as the last character of the string, it produces not match.

Comment: so can I change my regex to this **^\s*([\w]+)\s*\(.*?\)\s*$**

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to match from first ( bracket to last ) bracket hence I used $

Comment: I am still not sure what is the goal here. The match group ([\w]+) will capture only the text before the first opening parenthesis. Why do you want to match the rest of the string?

Comment: Yaa first should be text only and then followed by ( and any number of characters and last ) bracket